# Not able to get array variable contents after passing them from controller to views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am passing array after decoding it from controller to views.

**AddressController.php**

```
$pro = $request->input('pro');
$pro_array = json_decode($pro, true);

    Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => $title,'pro_array' => $pro_array, 'email' => $email, 'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname, 'addressline' => $addressline, 'Ttl' => $Ttl, 'phone' => $phone], function ($message) use ($email)
    {
        $message->from($email);
        $message->to('info@phalwala.com', 'Phalwala');
        $message->subject("Welcome To Phalwala");

    });
return redirect('/')
```

I only want name, price and quantity from the array but it is giving Trying to get property of non-object.

**send.blade.php**

```
@foreach($pro_array as $cartItem)
    <p>Products: {{$cartItem->name}}</p>
    <p>Unit Price: {{$cartItems->price}} X {{$cartItems->qty}}</p>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: hmm have you tried $cartItem['name'];

Comment: please mark my answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the key instead of trying to acces it like object:

```
@foreach($pro_array as $cartItem)
    <p>Products: {{$cartItem['name']}}</p>
    <p>Unit Price: {{$cartItems['price']}} X {{$cartItems['qty']}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using object-notation `$cartItem->name`. Your error says you're doing this on a `non-object`. `$pro_array`'s items are of type array, so you need to use array-notation `$cartItem['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

if `$pro_array` returns **array** use collection in controller

example: `$pro_array = collection($pro_array);`